# There is a full stop missing in the stackstatus header

Tags: bug, status-completed, grammar, stackstatus

I think maybe there's a full stop missing in the second sentence of the stackstatus header? It strikes me as odd that the first sentence has a full stop but the second sentence doesn't.

[image: stackstatus headers]

Comment: Well, the first sentence must have a full stop otherwise it would look really bad.

Comment: Speaking of [language differences](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qRrw2hDjnl4&t=25s)...

Comment: Come on, you don't like a little humor

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm sometimes slow at catching on... But I'm well humored, I laugh at jokes 3 times: when they tell the joke, when they explain it, and when I finally get it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full stop on [stackstatus.net](https://www.stackstatus.net) has been added

Comment: Bit by bit, stack status is getting into shape! ;)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Well, beats the dark ages in some ways, I guess.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder about it myself, to be honest, and I admit sometimes when things get annoying I catch myself before posting not-so-nice comment myself. But, we're all humans, and the ordinary users here feel helpless when their beloved product(s) are bugged and they get no response. This does not justify being not nice! If someone posting comment which is out of place, send them to my Den and I'll teach them a lesson. ;-)

Comment: I have more to say, but will try making it into a discussion, stay tuned. :)